# Javascript, jscolor and ajax-generating input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscolor

If i use such trick with jscolor (http://jscolor.com/):

```
<div id="test-div"></div>
```

in javascript, the next thing works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-div').html('<input type="text" id="test_input" value="449944" class="form-control jscolor" />');
});
```

but the another trick doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#test-div').html('<input type="text" id="test_input" value="449944" class="form-control jscolor" />');
    }, 1000);
});
```

How to put such to work. I want to use in ajax generated color list.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor")` after you dynamically created your elements.

`jscolor.init()` works the same but for some reason it doesn't work for everyone.

Check the working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#test-div').html('<input type="text" id="test_input" value="449944" class="form-control jscolor" />');
        jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>

<div id="test-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!